# How to access previous rows in custom SQL scalar function?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-function

I want to write my own SQL scalar function that calculates the mean between data points of a single column over a variable number of rows, based on a second column. I envision this function looking something like `WINDOWMEAN(data, mileage, 100)`. This would compute the mean of all `data` over the rows where the `mileage` is within 100 miles of that of the current row.

Example:

```
| data | mileage | 
|  10  |  1000   |
|  15  |  1009   |
|  20  |  1056   |
|  16  |  1098   |
|  13  |  1130   |
|  14  |  1200   |
```

With a query like `SELECT WINDOWMEAN(data, mileage, 100) AS a FROM t`, I would expect:

```
| data | mileage | a    |
|  10  |  1000   | 10   |
|  15  |  1009   | 12.5 |
|  20  |  1056   | 15   |
|  16  |  1098   | 15.25|
|  13  |  1130   | 16.33|
|  14  |  1200   | 13.5 |
```

`a` is calculated for each row as the mean of all rows within 100 miles of `mileage` that come before the current row.

Where I am getting stuck is how to access previous rows in a custom SQL function. I am not certain what I am trying to accomplish is even possible because I've yet to find documentation for accessing other rows in this way.

Whether specific to this solution or not, is there any way to access previous rows in a custom SQL scalar function?

*(I can make the assumption that the rows are ordered by mileage)*

Comment: You can't do that with a scalar function. You can probably, though, do what you want using the `avg()` window function with an appropriate range frame.

Comment: @Shawn I tried using window functions but couldn't figure out how to use a variable window size (like the example here). Per SQLite.org it doesn't look like the window can have a changing size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function with the appropriate `RANGE` frame definition to limit the window to rows within 100 miles of the current one:

```
SELECT data, mileage
     , avg(data) OVER (ORDER BY mileage RANGE BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS a
FROM t
ORDER BY mileage;
```

```
data        mileage     a
----------  ----------  ----------
10          1000        10.0
15          1009        12.5
20          1056        15.0
16          1098        15.25
13          1130        16.3333333
14          1200        13.5
```

---

Notes:

This query requires Sqlite 3.28 or newer, as that version had some major enhancements to window functions to allow, among other things, numeric ranges like this.

For best results, create an index on `t(mileage)` or a covering index on `t(mileage, data)`.

---

Non-window function version using a correlated subquery (Also works better with that index):

```
SELECT data, mileage
     , (SELECT avg(t2.data) FROM t AS t2
        WHERE t2.mileage BETWEEN t1.mileage - 100 AND t1.mileage) AS a
FROM t AS t1
ORDER BY mileage;
```

Comment: I tried running this query but get an error for `RANGE must use only UNBOUNDED or CURRENT ROW`. Also, isn't that looking at 100 preceding rows?

Comment: @mdmnd18 You're not using a recent enough version of sqlite then. It needs 3.28 or newer. And no, not 100 rows. `RANGE` is different from `ROWS` in a frame spec. See https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#frame_specifications for details.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server it's possible by using Window Functions ROW_NUMBER
This fonction exists for sqlite [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) but I'm not sure it'll work.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (data int ,mileage int)

--SOME DATA
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (10,1000),
        (15,1009),
        (20,1056)

--Replace @t by the real table name

;WITH TableWithRow(data, mileage, r)
AS
(
    SELECT data, mileage, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) 
    FROM @t
)
SELECT c.data, c.mileage, p.data previousData, p.mileage previousmileage
FROM TableWithRow c
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableWithRow p on c.r-1 = p.r

---WITHOUT CTE (bad performance)
SELECT c.data, c.mileage, p.data previousData, p.mileage previousmileage
FROM (
    SELECT data, mileage, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) r
    FROM @t
) c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT data, mileage, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) r
    FROM @t
) p on c.r-1 = p.r
```